# Return type for docstring

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

While documenting code, I like to put in the types of inputs and outputs. Currently I list methods inputs in the docstrings as so:

```
:param some_input: The method input.
:type some_input: str
```

Which compiles nicely to:

**Parameters**: some_input (str) – The method input.

In the above, 'str' actually links automatically to https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str. I would like to have the same thing for my returns as well, with the type listed and hopefully linked to documentation of the class. Following the tags on the sphinx site: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html, I have tried:

```
:return: The methods output.
:rtype: int
```

However this compiles to:

**Returns:**    The methods output.

**Return type:**    int

rather than listing the return name and type on one line. Is there a nice way to achieve the same result as for the param?

Sphinx is v1.6.4 and the theme is alabaster

Comment: While using `sphinx.ext.napoleon`, you have to set `napoleon_use_rtype = True` in your `conf.py`.